# Combining CMake option() with add_definitions()

Tags: c++, c, macros, cmake, conditional-compilation

Currently I have the following in my CMakeLists.txt (only the essential part for this question is listed below):

```
option(NORMALS_WITH_OPENMP "Enable OpenMP for estimating the normals of a point cloud" OFF)
if(NORMALS_WITH_OPENMP)
  message("OpenMP enabled")
  add_definitions(-DENABLE_OPENMP)
  set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -fopenmp")
endif()
```

In one of my source files I have:

```
#ifdef ENABLE_OPENMP
  #include <pcl/features/normal_3d_omp.h>
#else
  #include <pcl/features/normal_3d.h>
#endif
```

and other places in the code in that source file are also enabled/disabled in the same manner based on whether `ENABLE_OPENMP` has been defined or not.

My requirement for this is to be able give to brief description about the OpenMP support (using `option()`) and then if the option is set to **ON** add the `ENABLE_OPENMP` definition so that my code is compiled differently (using `add_definitions()`).

**Questions:**

- Is this the right way to do that or is there a more elegant way of handling the situation?
- Can I omit one of the two or do I really have to stick to both as a combination in order to fulfill the requirement I've listed above?

Thanks!

Comment: You use right way. Alternative for conditional `add_definitions()` could be unconditional `set(ENABLE_OPENMP ${NORMALS_WITH_OPENMP})` combined with `configure_file()` on file, contained line `#cmakedefine ENABLE_OPENMP` (and including resulted file into your source/headers). But there is no alternative for conditional appending `CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS`. Is this answered to your second question too, or it has another meaning?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use OpenMP only for this `NORMALS` feature, it's ok. Otherwise, you actually mixing two things - OpenMP usage and using it for `NORMALS`. Had you more optional features implemented with OpenMP, you should've do something like that:

```
find_package(OpenMP)

# enable OpenMP if compiler supports it
if(OpenMP_FOUND)
  set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} ${OpenMP_CXX_FLAGS}")
endif()

# let user choose each option if OpenMP is there
if(OpenMP_FOUND)
  option(NORMALS_WITH_OPENMP "Blabla" OFF)
  option(ANOTHER_THING_WITH_OPENMP "Blabla" ON)
endif()
```

Now you can either conditionally use `add_definitions(-DFEATURE)` or, as @Tsyvarev suggested, create an `config.h.cmake` file with lines

```
#cmakedefine NORMALS_WITH_OPENMP
#cmakedefine ANOTHER_THING_WITH_OPENMP
```

and `configure_file()` it, handling all definitions at once.

Comment: So let me clarify something - if I use the configuration file I don't need to use `add_definitions()` and can use `NORMALS_WITH_OPENMP` in my source code?

Comment: Btw since I'm using `gcc` the `find_package(OpenMP)` is useless and doesn't do anything.